# Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate() in php 5.512 using wampserver 2.5

Tags: php

I'm trying to use php function `transliterator_transliterate()` on my website but I get the `server error`

> Call to undefined function.

In php `error log` there is nothing else written about an `dll` or whatever that can cause this problem.
Why I can't use this function when php version is `5.5.12.`

Comment: And your PECL intl version?

Comment: You need to install php-intl package with command like `sudo apt install php-intl && sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`. [Source](https://www.jasom.net/php-prepare-sanitize-transliterate-convert-change-user-string-input-for-filename-or-url-address/)

Answer (score 14):

I was missing the `php-intl` package in my server, which actually has in it the `Transliterator` class, as you can see in the official PHP page: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php

Answer (score 0):

The installation of PEAR solved the problem.

@ihsan thanks!