# How to remove these iconv-translated ASCII question mark characters from this string?

Tags: php, iconv

I'm translating user-submitted strings from UTF-8 to ASCII-Printable:

```
$str = 'Thê qúïck  brõwn fõx júmps? Óvér thé lázy dõg?';

$out = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);

var_dump($out);

$out = 'The quick ? brown fox jumps?? Over the lazy dog??';
```

I want the extra `?` question marks from `$out` removed.

```
if ($out !== $str && strpos($out, '?') !== false) {
    // The input string was modified and contains at least one question mark
    //
    // Not even really sure where to begin
    //
    // Do we need to compare the position of every character from the
    // original string to every position of the new string and replace
    // where the original string did not contain a question mark?
    //
    // That's all I can think of, but there has to be a better way.
}
```

I want to keep all `//TRANSLIT` characters, including those few included in the example `$str` above, e.g.`áéïõú` = `aeiou`. There is no other nuace to this question. I think it boils down to a string comparison and replace question.

I'm not necessarily looking for someone to write the entire code, just a pointer in the right direction of how you'd tackle this.

Comment: Split the original input into code points (not characters!), convert each individually, and if the original is not a `?` but the translation is, dump it? Still horror as one char of the translation could be composed by several code points. Or split the original string by `?` and convert all the parts inbetween, removing any `?` as outcome.

Comment: Relevant: [Remove non-text chars (like emoticons) from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43097087/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [`transliterator_transliterate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php):

```php
$str = transliterator_transliterate('Latin-ASCII', 'Thê qúïck  brõwn fõx júmps? Óvér thé lázy dõg?');
$str = preg_replace('/[\x80-\xFF]/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
The quick  brown fox jumps? Over the lazy dog?
```

Note that the emoji are kept by `transliterator_transliterate()`, so I used a regex to remove all the remaining non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I don't have the `PECL-intl` extension installed on my server, per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51656845). I'm pretty confident yours works, so I'm marking it correct instead of mine. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Olivier When a two-part duplicate is asked, please supply the two separate dupe targets or vote to close as Needs More Focus.  Allowing the uniqueness requirement of asking a question to be circumvented by asking multipart questions is not beneficial to Stack Overflow.  If the two dupe targets do not contain your recommended insights, please post new answers there.

Comment: Pretty much any PHP task that can be completed in 3 or less lines of code is a duplicate question since 2015. Asking a new, unique, clear, on-topic question in 2023 is super hard unless discussing a feature released in the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, although I'm sure there are better solutions that people can come up with.

```
$str = 'Thê qúïck  brõwn fõx júmps? Óvér thé lázy dõg?';
$out = 'The quick ? brown fox jumps?? Over the lazy dog??';
```

Output

```
var_dump(remove_iconv_question_marks($str, $out));

// string(46) "The quick   brown fox jumps?  Over the lazy dog? "
```

Function

```
/**
 * strip_iconv_question_marks - Remove question marks left behind by iconv()
 * after translating UTF-8 strings to ASCII strings
 *
 * @param string $str_utf8
 * @param string $str_ascii
 *
 * @return string
 */

function strip_iconv_question_marks($str_utf8, $str_ascii) {
    $arr_utf8 = mb_str_split($str_utf8);
    $arr_ascii = mb_str_split($str_ascii);

    $count = count($arr_utf8);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($arr_ascii[$i] === '?') {
            if ($arr_utf8[$i] !== '?') {
                $arr_ascii[$i] = ' '; // Prefer blank space over removal
            }
        }
    }
    return implode($arr_ascii);
}
```

For PHP < 7.4.0

```
function mb_str_split($str, $len = 1) {
    $arr = [];
    $cnt = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len, 'UTF-8');
    }
    return $arr;
}
```